# Wordpress embed error

Tags: wordpress

I am new to the Wordpress thing. I am trying to embed (use iframe src=) with shinyApps on our lab website but the error msg

"The backup of this post in browser is different from the version below"

pops up every time I am updating the code. Then I would lose the code. I am not sure how to solve this problem and there aren't actually solution out there online.

Greatly appreciate if you happen to know the solutions to this.

Xp

Answer (score 0):

If this is shown every time you are trying to update the code on your Wordpress site (it doesn't matter which code) then it usually has to do something with a slight cookie corruption in your browser. This used to be a bug in one of the Firefox versions too, not a long ago.

Do try to do the same thing in a different browser or even a different computer.